# How can Emacs mouse capture in an X11 based terminal be disabled to enable copy and past?

Tags: spacemacs, copy-paste, mouse

I am using Spacemacs in a terminal in a desktop, ie `Konsole` and when I try to copy and paste I see that emacs is capturing mouse clicks.

Is it possible to disable Emacs mouse capture for copying and pasting with the mouse to work. Even if it can be toggled on and off that will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below should be added to the  `dotspacemacs/user-config` section in `.spacemacs`:

```lisp
(xterm-mouse-mode -1)
```

From documentation at http://spacemacs.org/doc/FAQ.html#make-copypaste-working-with-the-mouse-in-x11-terminals (section 2.16)